# Mootools inject cloned element

Tags: javascript, mootools, inject

I need to clone an element, once page is resized overwrite the current element that is there.

My current code, that does not work is as follows:

```
var clone = false;
window.addEvent("domready",function(){
    clone = $$('.view').clone();
    /* Wait for images to be 100% loaded otherwise they might not have width/height */
    var lazyloader = new LazyLoad({
        onComplete: function(){
            setupWall();
            window.addEvent('resize:throttle(1000)', function(){
                /* Delete old viewport and add back with cloned version */
                var view = $$('.view');
                if(view){
                    wall = null;
                    view.dispose();
                }
                var cloneElement = $$('#wrapper').inject(clone);
                console.log(cloneElement);
                //setupWall();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

When `$$('#wrapper').inject(clone);` runs I get the following error:

> Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

As suggested in the comments here is the html as well.

```
<div id="wrapper">  
    <section class="view" id="wall">
        <div class="panel" id="panel1"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/701/310" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel2"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/702/320" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel3"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/703/330" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel4"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/704/340" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel5"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/705/350" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel6"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/706/360" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel7"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/707/370" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel8"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/708/380" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel9"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/709/390" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel10"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/710/400" /></div>
        <div class="panel" id="panel11"><img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" data-src="http://placekitten.com/711/410" /></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Without the HTML it is difficult for anyone to debug or view what is happening with your code. The error message suggests that $$('#wrapper') is not matching an element in page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added the html to the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$$()` returns a collection. you should not clone a collection when you really want a single element.

if you mean to get a single element by id, use `$("id");` - if by selector, `document.getElement('.class')` (or any `node.getElement`). $'s not like in jquery, its more like `document.getElementById()`.

and also, `element.inject(target)` - single el, not collection - vs `target.adopt(element(s))`

```
window.addEvent("domready",function(){
    var clone = document.getElement('.view').clone();
    /* Wait for images to be 100% loaded otherwise they might not have width/height */
    var lazyloader = new LazyLoad({
        onComplete: function(){
            setupWall();
            window.addEvent('resize:throttle(1000)', function(){
                /* Delete old viewport and add back with cloned version */
                var view = $$('.view');
                if(view.length){
                    wall = null;
                    view.destroy();
                }
                var cloneElement = $('wrapper').adopt(clone);
                console.log(cloneElement);
                //setupWall();
            });
        }
    });
});
```